# pgfplots: changing line axis and plotting lines width

Tags: pgfplots, width

I have some problems with the width of the lines in my graph. When I try to change the width of the plot lines, straight lines remain in the default width whereas the non-straight lines are shown in the desired with. How can I change the width of the straigh line? Besides that, I want to know how to change the width of the axis lines (both x and y).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgf} %graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax = 4,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 50,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        xlabel= \footnotesize $x$,
        ylabel style={at={(current axis.north west)},rotate=-90,xshift=-1ex,yshift=-1ex},
        ylabel= \footnotesize $f(x)$,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty
        ]
        \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4,very thin]{30};
        \addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=0.2:3.8,very thick]{exp(x)+3};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine for me, but you need to zoom in a lot to see the difference between `very thin` and `thin` (the latter is the default line width). Try setting the straight line to `ultra thick` to verify that it's working. To change the axis line style, use `axis line style = ultra thick`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Note the thickness example noted above has gone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works fine for me, but you need to zoom in a lot to see the difference between `very thin` and `thin` (the latter is the default line width). Try setting the straight line to `ultra thick` to verify that it's working. To change the axis line style, use `axis line style = ultra thick`.